# "a breakpoint could not be inserted at this location" on RaiseEvent Statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

If I try to set a breakpoint on any line that uses the `RaiseEvent` statement I get:

> A breakpoint could not be inserted at this location.

[image]
I am in debug mode and I can use breakpoints everywhere else. All other debugging features are working fine; project compiles just fine.

If I can debug step on this line, why can't I put a breakpoint there?

Comment: Can you include a screen shot of what you're trying to do?  Something tells me there's more to it than what you've provided.

Comment: Screenshot is needed

Comment: @roryap, there you go

Comment: @konkked, there you go

Comment: Would assume that the actual `RaiseEvent` statement redirects somewhere else, or does some sort of dark magic behind the scenes, not a vb.net guy though

Comment: @konkked, yeah it's a delegate call. But in the code dom (or whatever intellisense, rename, etc. use), it's just another line of code. So, hmmm.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but hopefully this helps someone in the future...
I was getting the same error, but I had a syntax error that I had not noticed.  Rebuilding the project pointed out the error, and once it was fixed, I was then able to insert breakpoints like normal.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you don't have source (or debug info) access to the overloaded function. You can use a Stop statement (temporarily), or display information with a MsgBox.

Comment: Thanks. I did not find any overloads. Just to make sure, I made up a crazy event name and that would not host a breakpoint either. Thanks for the work-arounds. This question was mainly out of curiousity rather than work stoppage.

Comment: In other words, this answer is not the case in my case. Do you know why I can't set a breakpoint on this statement? Does it work for you?